# Save a plot as png file in react-plotly.js?

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I am using react-plotly.js library to plot histogram. I need to download the graph as a png file. I saw a [document](https://plot.ly/javascript/static-image-export/) on how to do it in plotly.js library. Can someone help me to figure out how to do it in react-plotly.js library. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

**just use this method to save png file**

```
downloadGraph(fileName) {
if(this.graphPlotted) {
  Plotly.downloadImage(this.graphPlotted, {format: 'png', filename: fileName})
}
```

}

Comment: If it solves the problem, please accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

if you have list of plotly charts in react inside an element, having id as "chart-container", then use the following code to download the graph as png, which can be called on any button click event.

```
let ele = document.getElementById('chart-container').getElementsByClassName('modebar');
for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    ele[i].getElementsByClassName('modebar-btn')[0].click();
}
```